# Parsing text in the RichTextBox using C#

Tags: c#, text

There is a sort of a HTML that is being read into a RichTextBox (see below).
Suppose there are multiple `<h3>` tags in the HTML as shown below. I need to write a method in c# that can parse the text in the RichTextBox `<h3>` and return me a comma separated string.

Suppose Titles with the tag `<h3>` are

```html
...<h3>Title1</h3> ...
...<h3>Title2</h3> ...
...<h3>Title3</h3> ...
```

Then the method should return 
Title1,Title2,Title3.

I thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your English, what are "shed Titles"? Do you want to extract text from HTML? Do you want to programmatically change the appreance of some HTML?

Comment: I do not understand English very well.I'm titles apart from text html

Comment: It rubs the lotion on its skin or else it gets the hose again

Comment: welcome to SO. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like that:

```
        string value = @"...<h3>Title1</h3> ......<h3>Title2</h3> ......<h3>Title3</h3> ...";

        List<string> ListOfTags = new List<string>();

        string[] split1 = value.Split(new string[] { "<h3>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in split1.Skip(1))
        {
            string[] split2 = item.Split(new string[] { "</h3>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ListOfTags.Add(split2[0]);
        }
        var result = String.Join(", ", ListOfTags.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        //Output => Title1, Title2, Title3
```